# Excel keeps crashing when we try a connection to sql11 datamart cubes

Tags: excel, database, office365

Our users are trying to access our cubes, but every time they select "Get Data" option in excel an error message pops up with no description, then Excel crash and open back by itself. We did a lot of troubleshooting, tried Quick repair, Online repair, uninstall-reinstall office, rollback to an older version, update office to a newer version, looked at our DB and no problem there... it happens to a couple of users, but they all have different versions of office, they are all using pretty much the same model of laptop. I am out of inspiration on how to fix this issue, any ideas?

thanks!

tried Quick repair, Online repair, uninstall-reinstall office, rollback to an older version, update office to a newer version, looked at our DB and no problem there